# Adding string element of list to another string causes attempt to add whole list?

Tags: python

I am trying to write code that will take an input such as "123/456" and seperate out the content from each side of the slash. So the correct answers would be put into 2 variables, the first called "leftof" with a value of "123" and a second variable called "rightof" with a value of "456".

My code:

```
testinput = "123/456"

inputlist = []
inputlist = list(testinput)

print(inputlist[0])
print("list elements are of ", type(inputlist[0]))

leftof = ''
rightof = ''

bool = 0


for x in inputlist :   
    if [x] == ("/") :
        bool =1
    else :
        if bool == 0:           
            leftof = leftof + [x]
        if bool == 1:           
            rightof = rightof + [x]    

print("left of slash is ", leftof)
print("right of slash is ", rightof)
```

And my Traceback:

```
C:\python>python ddd.py
1
list elements are of  <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ddd.py", line 20, in <module>
    leftof = leftof + [x]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I do not understand how it thinks I am trying to add a whole list. All help appreciated!

Comment: There's something very fishy about `if [x] == ("/"):` - this can never be true, because you are comparing a list with a string. I suspect you have written `[x]` thinking that doesn't mean "a list containing `x`", because you've done the same thing in three places. You probably just want to write `x` there.

Comment: When you put brackets around `x`, then you create a list with a single element.

Comment: `[x]` is a list, you're trying to add it to a string, thus the error.  All of the places you've written `[x]` should simply be `x`.  Or, use the more straightforward solution of `leftof, rightof = testinput.split("/")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets (`[]`) denote a list. `[x]` isn't "x" it's "a list of one element that is x". Lose the brackets and you should be OK:

```py
for x in inputlist :   
    if x == ("/") :
        bool =1
    else :
        if bool == 0:           
            leftof = leftof + x
        if bool == 1:           
            rightof = rightof + x
```

As a side note, though, you probably shouldn't implement this yourself, and just use the builtin `split` function like Frodon and Isin suggested.

Comment: This was the solution, thank you very much Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using the `split` function.

```
inputs = testinput.split('/')
leftof = inputs[0]
rightof = inputs[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.split()` function:

```
testinput = "123/456"
leftof, rightof = testinput.split('/')
```

Comment: good lord, hours i've spent working on this and you've blown me away with these two lines lol I've much yet to learn it seems, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
leftof = leftof + [x]
```

Here `leftof` is a string and `[x]` is a list with a single element.

There really is no reason to use lists at all here. You can iterate over each character in a string:

```
for x in testinput:
```